# Changing default index of a dataframe to a column

Tags: python, pandas

> I am trying to change the default index of my dataframe (stack overflow's survey of 2019) from **0-98854** to **1-101548** by setting the new index column to ***Respondent***. I will be, then, using this index to access individual rows with more precision compared to using the default index.

**1st try:** I have tried resetting the index using `df.reset_index(drop=True)` but it didn't seem to work.

**2nd try:** I've also tried using `df.set_index('Respondent', inplace=True)` but it didn't work either -- default index shows up first, and I can't search by label (e.g. `df.loc['3']` - `KeyError: '3'`).

Preview of the dataframe:

```
    Respondent Hobby OpenSource             Country  ... Dependents MilitaryUS                         SurveyTooLong     SurveyEasy      
0               1   Yes         No               Kenya  ...        Yes        NaN  The survey was an appropriate length      Very easy      
1               3   Yes        Yes      United Kingdom  ...        Yes        NaN  The survey was an appropriate length  Somewhat easy      
2               4   Yes        Yes       United States  ...        NaN        NaN                                   NaN            NaN      
3               5    No         No       United States  ...         No         No  The survey was an appropriate length  Somewhat easy      
4               7   Yes         No        South Africa  ...        Yes        NaN  The survey was an appropriate length  Somewhat easy      
...           ...   ...        ...                 ...  ...        ...        ...                                   ...            ...      
98850      101513   Yes        Yes       United States  ...        NaN        NaN                                   NaN            NaN      
98851      101531    No        Yes               Spain  ...        NaN        NaN                                   NaN            NaN      
98852      101541   Yes        Yes               India  ...        NaN        NaN                                   NaN            NaN      
98853      101544   Yes         No  Russian Federation  ...        NaN        NaN                                   NaN            NaN      
98854      101548   Yes        Yes            Cambodia  ...        NaN        NaN                                   NaN            NaN
```

Comment: `df.set_index('Respondent', inplace=True)` should work, can you provide a [mcve] where it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

`df.set_index('Respondent', inplace=True)` should work. No reason it shouldn't. `df.loc['3']` won't work because your index is an int, not a string. Try `df.loc[3]`.